# laravel mix not importing all files. upgrading to laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

I want to upgrade laravel 5,3 to 5.4, but while i updating laravel mix i go such eorrors.
In my webpack.mix.js , i include this files:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.styles([
            'bootstrap.min.css',
            'bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css',
            'select2-bootstrap.css',
            'font-awesome.min.css',
            'smartadmin-production-plugins.min.css',
            'smartadmin-production.min.css',
            'smartadmin-skins.min.css',
            'menu.css',
            'chosen.min.css',
            'your_style.css'

        ],
        'public/smartadmin/css/all.css',
        'resources/assets/smartadmin/css');

    /*main js*/
    mix.scripts([
            'plugin/pace/pace.min.js',
            'libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js',
            'libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js',

        ],
        'public/smartadmin/js/jquery.js',
        'resources/assets/smartadmin/js');

    mix.scripts([
            'app.config.js',
            '/plugin/jquery-touch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js',
            '/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js',
            // '/bootstrap/moment.js',
            '/bootstrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js',
            '/notification/SmartNotification.min.js',
            '/smartwidgets/jarvis.widget.min.js',
            '/plugin/easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.min.js',
            '/plugin/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js',
            '/plugin/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js',
            '/plugin/masked-input/jquery.maskedinput.min.js',
            '/plugin/select2/select2.min.js',
            '/plugin/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.min.js',
            '/plugin/bootstrap-timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js',
            '/plugin/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js',
            '/plugin/clockpicker/clockpicker.min.js',
            '/plugin/msie-fix/jquery.mb.browser.min.js',
            '/plugin/fastclick/fastclick.min.js',
            '/plugin/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js',
            'app.min.js',
            '/smart-chat-ui/smart.chat.ui.min.js',
            '/smart-chat-ui/smart.chat.manager.min.js',
            '/nestable/jquery.nestable.js',
            '/plugin/summernote/summernote.min.js',
            '/smartwidgets/jarvis.widget.min.js',
            '/plugin/easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.min.js',
            '/plugin/fastclick/fastclick.min.js',
            'site.js'

        ],
        'public/smartadmin/js/all.js',
        'resources/assets/smartadmin/js');
     /*charts*/
        mix.scripts([
            'plugin/flot/jquery.flot.cust.min.js',
            'plugin/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js',
            'plugin/flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js',
            'plugin/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js',
            'plugin/vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js',
            'plugin/vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js',
            'plugin/moment/moment.min.js',
            'plugin/fullcalendar/jquery.fullcalendar.min.js',
            'plugin/morris/raphael.min.js',
            'plugin/morris/morris.min.js',

        ],
        'public/smartadmin/js/charts.js',
        'resources/assets/smartadmin/js');

    /*stream datatable*/

    mix.scripts([
            'plugin/streamtable/stream_table.js',
            'plugin/streamtable/mustache.js',

        ],
        'public/smartadmin/js/streamtable.js',
        'resources/assets/smartadmin/js');

    /*stream table*/
    mix.scripts([
            'plugin/bootstrap-wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js',
            'plugin/fuelux/wizard/wizard.min.js',

        ],
        'public/smartadmin/js/wizard.js',
        'resources/assets/smartadmin/js');
    /*stream table*/
    mix.scripts([
            'plugin/streamtable/table.js',

        ],
        'public/smartadmin/js/table.js',
        'resources/assets/smartadmin/js');
```

**after run npm run dev it gives:**

```
     Asset      Size  Chunks               Chunk Names
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1 20.1 kB [emitted]
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg?89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760 109 kB [emitted]
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf?e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512 45.4 kB [emitted]
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff?fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158 23.4 kB [emitted]
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2?448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb 18 kB [emitted]
/js/app.js 1.17 MB 0 [emitted] [big] /js/app
/css/app.css 683 kB 0 [emitted] [big] /js/app
mix-manifest.json 66 bytes [emitted]
```

Previously i used elixer...
**in my package.json i have:**

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch-poll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
"axios": "^0.15.3",
"cross-env": "^3.2.3",
"laravel-mix": "^0.8.8",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"vue": "^2.1.10",
"webpack": "^2.2.1"
},
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.15.2",
"ioredis": "^2.5.0",
"socket.io": "^1.7.3"
}
}
```

i tried every method of laravel mix to fix this and also sees reference for this but i cant get any solutions, Is there possible to use elixer.
i have :
Laravel Mix Version: 0.8.1
Node Version (node -v): 6.9.1
NPM Version (npm -v): 4.2
OS: ubuntu 16.4 lts

Comment: Can you paste the errors you get?

Comment: bro i mentioned above i did not get files in public folder...

Comment: _but while i updating laravel mix i go such eorrors_

Answer (score 1):

[Upgrading to Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade)

Laravel Tinker is now a stand-alone package, and installation is simple.

Require the package and include the service provider:

> composer require laravel/tinker

When that finishes, add the service provider to your config/app.php file:

> Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider

Your existing tests that utilize browser kit will either need to be migrated to Laravel Dusk or include the [older package](https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing):

> composer require laravel/browser-kit-testing --dev

To get the latest version modify your composer.json file and change the laravel/framework dependency to 5.4.*.

[Source](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4)

Comment: did you follow the other steps?

Comment: glad that helped you